# How to manually invoke actionPerformed in Java?

Tags: java, swing, actionlistener

The method `actionPerformed` of class `ActionListener` is invoked when we **click** on a (let say) JButton. I want to run this method manually in a program. Is it possible?
Here is an example:

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // do something
    }  
});
```

This `actionPerformed` is invoked when I click on `button`. Is there another way to call it manually using a line(s) of code in my program?

Comment: it's a method like any other. How can one invoke a method? Just create the listener in another class, not in an anonymous implementation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can:

- Call `.doClick()` on the button
- Simply call `actionPerformed(null)` on the method ... difficult if the method is in an anonymous class
- Call `getActionListeners()` on the JButton and iterate through the `ActionListener[]` array that is returned, calling each listener's actionPerformed method
- Or have the listener itself call a method that the main program can call (my preferred way):

```
public void someMethod() {
    // has code that the listener needs done
}
```

```
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        someMethod();  // call it here in the listener
    }  
});
```

```
// in another part of the code, call the same method
someMethod();
```